# onItemClickListener not working in GridView using CustomAdaptor in Android

Tags: android

I have an activity which let user click on any mood he is in. I have created a gridView and inflated it with relative layout containing an imageView and a textView. I have set a customAdaptor to it. I have set onItemClickListener on gridView but it is not responding.

Java class and adaptor class

```
public class SelectMoodActivity extends Activity {
    protected ArrayList<Moods> data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_mood);

        data = MoodProvider.getData();
        ArrayAdapter<Moods> moodsArrayAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, data);
        GridView gridView = findViewById(R.id.moodSelect);
        gridView.setAdapter(moodsArrayAdapter);


        /*
        Tried to setOnClickEvent for MOOD Select */
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You selected a Mood", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }


    class CustomGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Moods> {
        Context context;
        ArrayList<Moods> moodsArrayList;
        int resource;

        public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Moods> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            this.context = context;
            this.moodsArrayList = objects;
            this.resource = resource;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(view == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                view = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.moodTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
                holder.moodIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
                view.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder  = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            Moods mood  = moodsArrayList.get(position);
            holder.moodTitle.setText(mood.getMoodTitle());
            int res = context.getResources().getIdentifier(mood.getMoodIcon(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
            holder.moodIcon.setImageResource(res);

            /*
            Tried to setOnClickEvent for MOOD Select inside the adaptor but this also didn't work.
            view.setId(position);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter All Details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            */

            return view;

        }

    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView moodTitle;
        ImageView moodIcon;
    }

}
```

XML Files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="net.moodsense.moodsense.SelectMoodActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textMood"
        android:id="@+id/textMood"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/moodSelect"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textMood"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

row_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/item_image"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try after adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`  to your Root item layout .

Comment: remove android:focusable="false"     android:focusableInTouchMode="false" from your row item views and check

Answer (score 1):

make one interface in custom adapter class and used in click event like below code ...

```
    onItemClickListner onItemClickListner;

public void setOnItemClickListner(CustomGridViewAdapter.onItemClickListner onItemClickListner) {
    this.onItemClickListner = onItemClickListner;
}

public interface onItemClickListner {
        void onClick();// hear you can pass any type of data as a argument;
}
```

then after getView() method in adapter class define below code for click event handleing.

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onItemClickListner.onClick();
            }
        });
```

then after you bind adapter in grid view used below code in activity when you define adapter object for event handleing..

```
    moodsArrayAdapter.setOnItemClickListner(new CustomGridViewAdapter.onItemClickListner() {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello world",0).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

add **android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants** in rawGrid>RelativLayout

and add

**focusable="false"** in rawGrid>RelativLayout>textview, rawGrid>RelativLayout>imageview

and

**focusable="true"** in gridview

Comment: You can use onTouchListener.

Comment: `onTouchListener`? Seriously  ? For OnClick.

Comment: if you have tried all the way of onClick and its not work then another way is onTouch if you want

Comment: Wait i am finding solution for onClick() if i got then tell you otherwise onTouch is there.

Comment: I have tried it as you suggested but it didn't work.

Comment: try android:focusableInTouchMode="false" with of focusable="false",focusable="true" as per my answer.. try it and see if work.

Comment: check there are any property of gridview "android:clickable" if there then set  android:clickable="true" in gridview

Comment: aahhh,   What is problem with us ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167010/discussion-between-shubham-jain-and-sahdevrajput74).

Comment: @SahdevRajput74 Thank you for the help. It worked when i just used the clean code feature in android studio and restarted it. I still don't know what was the cause of issue.